# hline/vline with subplots in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook, julia-plots

I'm trying to add a horizontal line to a subplot, and from this discussion: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/vline-with-subplots/25479/2, I have the following

```
x = [1,2,3]
y1 = 2x
y2 = x.^2
plot([x, x], [y1, y2], layout = (2, 1))
hline!([4 4])
```

Which produces the plots.

[image: plots]

Now what I'm trying to do is do the horizontal line on the bottom plot, but not the top one. If I just specify `hline!([4])` , it defaults to the top one. Is there a way to do the bottom one only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best practice to plot subplots separately (as mentioned on Slack by isentropic):

```
x = [1,2,3]
y1 = 2x
y2 = x.^2
p1 = plot(x, y1)
p2 = plot(x, y2)
hline!(p2, [4])
plot(p1, p2, layout = (2, 1))
```

But if you want it all in one go, you could have used

```
hline!([[NaN], [4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to keep track of the plot handles.

```
p = plot([x, x], [y1, y2], layout = (2, 1))
```

returns a plot handle (specifically, a `Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}` object) `p` with two elements, `p[1]` (the first subplot) and `p[2]` (the second subplot). To add the hline to the bottom plot only, then, you can write:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y1 = 2x
y2 = x.^2
p = plot([x, x], [y1, y2], layout = (2, 1))
hline!(p[2], [4])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Good to know subplots are tracked as an array with the handle,